# Can't create trigger in Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm using Realm in iOS, I have user table and history table.When user table's record is updated or created,I want to create a trigger to save this event in history table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Notifications section](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#notifications) of Realm documentation. You should use a notification token to listen changes made to your User table and then run the code that saves the event to History table in the notificationBlock of the token.